# Can't add System.Windows.Media.Imaging.JpegBitmapEncoder in WP

Tags: windows-phone-7, serialization, jpeg, system.windows.media

I'm trying to use the type `JpegBitmapEncoder`in the name space `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`, but i can't seem to use it. The namespace itself is available and i can use it but for some reason the JpegBitmapEncoder is not there... How can i use it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the extension methods on [WritableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) to load and save a jpeg instead.

[Extensions Methods - LoadJpeg, SaveJpeg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions_methods%28VS.92%29.aspx)

If you want to get a byte array from the image, use a `MemoryStream` and its [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) to get the data.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
image.SaveJpeg(stream, width, height, 0, 80);
stream.Position = 0;
byte[] buffer = stream.ToArray();
```

Comment: also another question.. does it work on image of the type: System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage ?

Comment: @YonatanNir: Yes, the WritableBitmap constructor takes a BitmapSource (which BitmapImage inherits from) so you simply write `new WritableBitmap(bitmapSource);` and then use the code above